# How to export Elasticsearch Index as CSV file to Google Cloud Storage Using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-7, google-cloud-storage

I am using ElasticSearch, here we are creating the day wise index and huge amount of data is being ingested every minute. wanted to export few fields from index created every day to Google cloud storage. am able to achieve this with output file as json as shown below:

```
input {

 elasticsearch {

    hosts => "localhost:9200"

    index => "test"


    query => '

    {
    "_source": ["field1","field2"],

    "query": {

    "match_all": {}

    }
    filter {
    mutate {
        rename => {
            "field1" => "test1"
            "field2" => "test2"
        }
      }
     }

    }

  '

  }

}


output {
   google_cloud_storage {
   codec => csv {
    include_headers => true
    columns => [ "test1", "test2" ]
   }
     bucket => "bucketName"
     json_key_file => "creds.json"
     temp_directory => "/tmp"
     log_file_prefix => "logstash_gcs"
     max_file_size_kbytes => 1024
     date_pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00"
     flush_interval_secs => 600
     gzip => false
     uploader_interval_secs => 600
     include_uuid => true
     include_hostname => true
   }
}
```

**However how to export it as CSV file and send it to Google Cloud Storage**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change `output_format` to `plain` but this setting is going [to be deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage.html#plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage-output_format)

You should remove `output_format` and use the [`codec` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/8.6/plugins-codecs-csv.html) instead, which supports a [`csv` output format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-csv.html)

```
google_cloud_storage {
   ...
    codec => csv {
        include_headers => true
        columns => [ "field1", "field2" ]
    }
}
```

If you want to rename your fields, you can add a `filter` section and [`mutate/rename`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename) the fields however you like. Make sure to also change the `columns` settings in your csv codec output:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        rename => {
            "field1" => "renamed1"
            "field2" => "renamed2"
        }
    }
}
output {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Verymuch @Val , above solution worked, how can we use different names for these columns present in csv, instead of field names from elastic search we want to use different column names in CSV

Comment: thankyou @Val  for your quick response, have updated .conf file in the question, can you please check if i am using filter properly

Comment: the filter section goes between the input and the output section at the top level

Comment: Hi @Val one more quick question how to move the output file to folder inside GCS bucket, instead of directly placing inside bucket. from the above .conf file it is placing directly in bucket

Comment: Have you tried to specify the folder in the bucket name directly `bucket => "bucketName/folder1/folder2/"`?

Comment: Yes @Val, It failed to upload the file if we specify folder name along with bucket Name

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible then

Comment: Hi @Val , do you have any suggestions on this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334058/how-to-export-nested-fields-in-elasticsearch-index-as-csv-file-to-google-cloud-s